# Dependancy Removal for Junit test case

Tags: java

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(" + genusNames + ")[^\\p{L}][^\uFF00]").matcher(inputText);
        while(m.find()){
            if(!StateMachine.checkFormatRoman(m.group(1).length(), m.start()))
                createDecision(m.group(1), "&lt;Roman&gt;" + m.group(1) + "&lt;/Roman&gt;", m.start());
    }
```

In the above code checkFormatRoman method is from another class. What should i do to remove dependancy of this method, note the value supplied to this method is obtained dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should mock your static method `StateMachine.checkFormatRoman`. You can do so using [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

You can return desired value you want.

Something like..

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StateMachine.class);
PowerMockito.when(StateMachine.checkFormatRoman(5, "IIIIL")).thenReturn(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `StateMachine.checkFormatRoman` is `static`. You could re-design this as follows:

```
class StateMachine {
    static class Implementation implements ImplementationInterface {
        ...
    }

    ImplementationInterface impl;

    public StateMachine () {
        impl = new Implementation ();
    }

    public StateMachine (ImplementationInterface alternative) {
        impl = alternative;
    }

    public ... checkFormatRoman (...) {
        return impl.checkFormatRoman (...);
    }
}
```

Now you can, for testing purposes, create a StateMachine with a dummy implementation by creating the instance with `machine = new StateMachine (dummyImplementation);`.

Alternative approach:

Re-design the class you are testing such that you can specify which function to call for `checkFormatRoman`:

```
class MyClass { // the class you are testing
    public interface Helpers {
        ... checkFormatRoman ...
    }

    static class HelpersDefault implements Helpers {
        ... checkFormatRoman ... {
            return StateMachine.checkFormatRoman (...);
        }
    }

    Helpers helpers = new HelpersDefault ();

    public void setHelpers (Helpers alternativeHelpers) {
        helpers = alternativeHelpers;
    }

    ... // your methods, calling, e.g., helpers.checkFormatRoman instead of
    // StateMachine.checkFormatRoman
}

// testing
...
objToTest = new MyClass ();
objToTest.setHelpers ( new MyClass.Helpers {
   // ... test dummy implementation of checkFormatRoman goes here
});
```

Or remove the dependency of your class to StateMachine entirely by defining an interface for `StateMachine` and passing a state machine argument upon construction.